# How to do marker/annotation clustering?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

I've looked in a lot of places to find how to do pin clustering in Xamarin.Forms.Maps but most solutions seems deprecated or there might be better ones since then.

I know I'll have to create a custom renderer, but since most solutions involved the Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps nuget instead of the Xamarin.Forms.Maps and/or using 3rd party libraries, I prefer to ask the community if anyone know or could redirect me to what should I put into my custom renderer ?

I have looked at the [Google Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering) way, the [iOS MapKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/2867923-mapview?language=objc) way, but I have no idea how to implement it in the C# way. I'm pretty much a beginner with custom renderers and especially Android and iOS code in Xamarin.Forms.

My map, pins and everything else work fine, so I should be able to implement your solutions pretty quickly and give you feedback pretty fast.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The cluster is not supported in Xamarin.Forms.Maps yet, you may want to post a feauture request or just use Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps instead.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer, do you know of any ways that it could be achieved using third party libraries maybe ? I tried to use Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps mutliple times but it never worked for some reason and I feel I'm too far in my project using custom code around Xamarin.Forms.Maps to change if that makes sense. Of course I'm not disregarding your idea I'll try it out if there are no other ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To use this feauture, you can try **Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps**.

It brings support for clustering for library Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps, you can follow the Usage of this library and try this sample first
:
https://github.com/mierzynskim/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Clustering/tree/master/Sample

Comment: Thank you Adrain, is this way of doing it the better way over third party libraries we can find online ?

Comment: I can't tell which way is better, it depends on different situations